# Simple frame with tk in python

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to write a code that prints a `Frame` to the screen with a `Button` and 
`Canvas` in it

```
import tkinter as tk
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Get", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()
        self.entry.pack()
        self.text =tk.Text(height=20,width=10)
        self.text.pack()
        self.canvas=tk.Canvas(fill='Black')
        self.canvas.pack()
    def on_button(self):
        print(self.entry.get())
app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

As soon as I run it, I get an error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-fill"
```

I have no idea why.

Comment: *"I have no idea why."* < really?! The error message seems pretty unambiguous (and, as you see the full traceback, tells you exactly which line is the problem): `tk.Canvas(fill='Black')` has an option, `fill`, that isn't known (see e.g. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.config-method).

Answer (score 1):

Fill is a `create_rectangle` argument, not a constructor argument:

```
self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, width, height, fill = "black")
```

Answer (score 1):

The canvas doesn't use a `fill` option to define what the background is; the error is coming out of the lower levels of the Tkinter code where it flips to the underlying Tcl/Tk runtime; option names get a hyphen put in front of them, and the error otherwise means what it says, “don't know what `fill` is in this context” (paraphrased).

However, the canvas *does* use a `background` option that takes a colour. Try:

```
    self.canvas=tk.Canvas(background='Black')
```

You can also create rectangles on the canvas; *those* are fillable. The overall canvas isn't a rectangle, it's a widget.